# Best practices for binding properties to a callback in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

As a self learner I've found the `kivy` binding action (mainly in `python`) a bit confusing. I've seen in many *source code* and/or *examples* in kivy that some of the properties are bounded to a callback in the constructor, while others are not (though used in those callback). My queries are:

1. Do I need to *bind* every created (or, custom) or provided (by kivy) properties to a callback (whenever needed to keep updated) ?
2. In any case which is the better option, *bind* or *fbind* ?
3. Does scheduling a callback have any advantages (particularly during widget creation)?

My corresponding assumptions are:

1. Only bind those properties that are inter-related or inter-dependent along with those used for *canvas* drawing. Rest will be managed or updated internally by kivy.
2. Almost results in the same thing (except depends on the implicit or explicit naming)
3. As per Kivy-doc widget creation is relatively slow, that's why scheduling is necessary.

(This is a re-post of a topic that I posted earlier with the same title but got no response from the community.)

I have not found any descriptive, informative article on this so far.
I need your proper guidance, thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.